# Receiving SMS , part of project (returning char and sizeof out of function)

Tags: c, linux, sms, embedded, gsm

I'm asking for help to return from this function content and length of buffer

```
void UART_rx(void)
     {
    char rx_buffer[256];
    memset(rx_buffer,'\0',256);
    int rx_length = read(uart_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer));
    if(rx_length < 0){
        printf("uart rx error\n");
    }
    printf("RX: %s", rx_buffer);
      }
```

[This](http://kannupandiyan.blogspot.com/2014/05/sending-and-receiving-sms-using-sim300.html) is code I'm  trying to modify

```
int8_t   SIM300WaitForMsg(uint8_t *id)
{
   //Wait for a unsolicited response for 250ms  
   uint8_t len=SIM300WaitForResponse(250);

   if(len==0)
      return SIM300_TIMEOUT;

   sim300_buffer[len-1]='\0';

   //Check if the response is +CMTI (Incoming msg indicator)
   if(strncasecmp(sim300_buffer+2,"+CMTI:",6)==0)
   {
      char str_id[4];

      char *start;

      start=strchr(sim300_buffer,',');
      start++;

      strcpy(str_id,start);

      *id=atoi(str_id);

      return SIM300_OK;
   }
   else
      return SIM300_FAIL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters for that, like this

```
void UART_rx(char *rx_buffer, ssize_t *rx_length)
{
    memset(rx_buffer, '\0', rx_length);
    *rx_length = read(uart_filestream, (void *) rx_buffer, *rx_length);
    if (*rx_length < 0)
        printf("uart rx error\n");
    printf("RX: %s", rx_buffer);
}
```

and call it like this

```
char rx_buffer[256];
ssize_t rx_length;

rx_length = sizeof(buffer);
UART_rx(rx_buffer, &rx_length);
```

It is very important to allocate the space in the caller funcion, also note how `rx_length` is useful in two ways, to let `UART_rx()` know the length of the destination buffer, and to store the length of the read data.

Also, you should not need to `memset()` anything, if you MUST do it that indicates a bug in your code, in fact this is how your function should be written

```
void UART_rx(char *rx_buffer, ssize_t *rx_length)
{
    *rx_length = read(uart_filestream, (void *) rx_buffer, *rx_length - 1);
    if (*rx_length < 0)
        printf("uart rx error\n");
    rx_buffer[*rx_length] = '\0';
    printf("RX: %s", rx_buffer);
}
```

And finally, this `uart_filestream` being a global variable can be thought as a bad sign too. It is preferred to use another parameter to `UART_rx()` and that would be `uart_filestream`, that way the function will be more useful and the whole code will be more robust.